# g++ installation on bash on ubuntu on windows

Tags: c++, windows, bash, ubuntu

when I tried to install g++ on bash on ubuntu on windows I am getting error

`

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.4.0-96.119_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-dev_2.23-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/libstdc++-5-dev_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/g++-5_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.4.0-96.119_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-dev_2.23-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/libstdc++-5-dev_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

 E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/g++-5_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
```

`

Comment: This question is for https://askubuntu.com C++ is not a subject here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably your apt cache is outdated. Try running `apt-get update` first. The version you tried to install is no longer in the repos anymore.